# vertx jdbc client connection Exception in thread "vertx-jdbc-service-get-connection-thread"

Tags: java

Please I'm new to vert.x help, I created a vertx API which is making use of mysql server to persist data. I don't know how I ran into the below error that I'm finding so difficult to fix:

```
 - MLog clients using log4j logging.
 - Initializing c3p0-0.9.5.2 [built 08-December-2015 22:06:04 -0800; debug? true; trace: 10]
Deployed: server.Server
 - Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, contextClassLoaderSource -> caller, dataSourceName -> 1hge2jo9g1k7ofepv0cdzu|1a2e3314, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, extensions -> {}, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, forceSynchronousCheckins -> false, forceUseNamedDriverClass -> false, identityToken -> 1hge2jo9g1k7ofepv0cdzu|1a2e3314, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/isec_play?user=root&password=root, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 30, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 0, minPoolSize -> 3, numHelperThreads -> 3, preferredTestQuery -> null, privilegeSpawnedThreads -> false, properties -> {}, propertyCycle -> 0, statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, userOverrides -> {}, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]




Exception in thread "vertx-jdbc-service-get-connection-thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.vertx.core.impl.VertxInternal.createWorkerContext(ZLjava/lang/String;Lio/vertx/core/json/JsonObject;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Lio/vertx/core/impl/ContextImpl;
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCConnectionImpl.<init>(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:55)
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCClientImpl.lambda$getConnection$3(JDBCClientImpl.java:100)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This happened to me after I modified my gradle build and started using jitpack to pull in vertx-redis-client via the latest commit on github. Perhaps your issue is incompatible library versions? Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: For now the only work around i have for this, is to reinstall the database completely and install it back again. I'm still looking for what i did wrong so that i can have a better fix for this.

Comment: glad to hear its working.... My issue was resolved by ensuring all the vert libraries were running on the same version. When i pulled the vertx-redis library from github it was at 3.3.0 whereas the rest of my libraries were at 3.2.1 I think. Probably incompatible transitive dependencies caused my issue.